# How is it possible to have two objects with the same name in Java?

Tags: java, exception, object

So I am learning java, and would still consider myself a beginner, only to get "noob-friendly" responses, and I am not stuck but just wondering how something is possible.

Here is my code:

```
import java.net.*;

public class HomePage {
String owner;
URL address;
String category;

public HomePage(String inOwner, String inAddress)
    throws MalformedURLException {

    owner = inOwner;
    address = new URL(inAddress);
}

public HomePage(String inOwner, String inAddress, String inCategory)
    throws MalformedURLException {

    this(inOwner, inAddress);
    category = inCategory;
}
}
```

Now my question is this: How is it possible to make two objects (HomePage) with the same name, and handling almost identical things (with the exception of inCategory in the second HomePage)?

In this section I am learning how to handle errors, so this class is used by another class which I understand. But I am not sure why I am able, and why I do, create two objects that are almost identical. Thanks!

For reference, here is the other class in the compilation:
(due to reputation and links in the code, I had to pastebin)

Comment: Those are not two objects. Those are two constructors. And you can have any number of overloaded constructors in your class.

Comment: Here is the link sorry [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Tq0SLjCY)

Comment: Hrm, so why would you think I use the same constructor names?

Comment: @David - because you may have different parameter(s) for the constructor. Google for "Method overloading" to get an explanation.

Comment: Does this allow for the optional use of inCategory like the book says?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> almost identical things (with the exception of inCategory in the second HomePage)

Exactly as you say: they're not the same. A method's uniqueness is determined by its signature which consists of the method name and its arguments. You can have the same name as long as the arguments differ in type and/or amount.

Do note that you're talking about constructors here. The term you're looking for is `overloading`.

As you can see the second constructor uses `this(inOwner, inAddress);`. This calls the first constructor with the given arguments. It makes sure you don't have to copy code to reach the same effect. The reason for multiple constructors is to allow outside classes to create an object with different arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It did help. I posted in a comment on my question the link to the class that uses this class (if needed). Now, would it not just be easier to make one homepage with everything?

Comment: Then what would you do if you want to create a homepage without a category? Passing a `null` value to a constructor is rather ugly. For a simple assignment operation it might not seem that big of a deal, but what if you need to perform more complex logic? What if the 3rd argument is of type `Category` and in the constructor you use the fields `CategoryID` and `CategoryName`. If you pass a `null` value this would mean you'd have to check if your arguments are not null, etc etc. your code would get very messy.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating two objects. The two constructors with different parameters are simply used to initialize the fields in the object. An object is an instance of a class and everything in the class is part of the same object. This is an example of method overloading so don't get confused between methods and objects.

Answer (score 1):

First of all.. They are not objects. 
They are the constructors for the class HomePage. 
It is possible to have multiple methods and multiple constructors with the same name. This process of using same names for multiple methods or constructors with different signature is referred to as OVERLOADING.

In your case, the constructors have a different signature

```
    public HomePage(String inOwner, String inAddress) throws MalformedURLException{...}
    public HomePage(String inOwner, String inAddress, String inCategory)throws MalformedURLException{..}
```

FYI : Please go through [Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating two objects that are identical.

Those two are constructors so you can simply calling one constructor to assist in constructing the actual object.

`public HomePage(String inOwner, String inAddress)` already has the code to set the properties owner and address so to avoid code duplication, you can just call it in `public HomePage(String inOwner, String inAddress, String inCategory)` to set those two properties then add the line `category = inCategory;` to initialize the category.

Comment: And the second homepage just adds inCategory? In the book it says the inCategory is optional, so is this what the second homepage does? Make it to where inCategory doesn't necessarily have to be used?

Comment: The second HomePage is what you call when you pass in a specific inOwner, inAddress, and inCategory. Yes, inCategory is optional because there exists the first HomePage which only requires inOwner and inAddress, so it is possible to create a HomePage object without specifying a category.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing an example of [method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

In this case it is the constructor that is being overloaded in order to make a type of `HomePage` using different sets of parameters (you can make an instance even if you don't know `inCategory`).

Comment: Oh, so having two of them allows for it to be used even if inCategory isn't present? Because in the book it said inCategory was optional. Is that what is happening here?

Comment: Thanks! (blank space)